# I want to store a id value in a variable ex $id=76

Tags: arrays, associative

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 76
            [header_left] => http://localhost/kaladisha/uploads/Lighthouse9.jpg
            [header_right] => http://localhost/kaladisha/uploads/Jellyfish3.jpg
            [content_topic] => 
            [content_subtopic] => 
            [content] => 
            [footer_img1] => 
            [footer_img2] => 
            [footer_img3] => 
            [footer_img4] => 
        )

)
```

I want to store the `id` value in a variable, for example:

```
$id = 76
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your array variable name is `$array`

```
$id = $array[0]->id
```